# generate_series() postgresql equivalent in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I need to populate a huge table on cassandra with dummy data, i really miss the pg function generate series().

```
postgres=# insert into non_fdw_table select 'col1' as col1, 2 as col2 , generate_series(1,100000) as col3;
INSERT 0 100000
```

Is there any equivalent function or way to generate rows within cassandra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's not possible with native cql.

Instead just write a simple script to generate the required inserts  :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Generating Inserts"
echo "" > inserts.cql

for i in {1..1000}
do
 INSERT_QUERY="insert into table(col1,col2) values(${i},$(($i*$RANDOM)));"
 echo $INSERT_QUERY >> inserts.cql
done
```

If you need dummy text , just use some string and club it with `$RANDOM`.